# How to send HTML format email with emebbed images(not attachment ) using Outlook 2010(no smtp) and python

Tags: python, html, outlook

Just as shown below, currently I have already implemented sending HTML format email using Outlook 2010 and python

```
def send_mail_via_com(self):
  o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
  Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
  Msg.To = self.myEmailAddress 
  Msg.BCC = self.myEmailAddress

  Msg.Subject = 'This is Subject'
  Msg.HTMLBody  = htmlEmailContent
  Msg.Send()
```

Going forward, I want to show some embed images in the HTML format email, I've check the the HTML source, it looks like following:

```
 <img border=0 width=117 height=20 id="Picture_x0020_2" src="cid:image001.png@01CE9386.AB9B5E70" alt="Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: Description: cid:786FB7C2-A5F6-462A-B0FD-EA865CD02221@xxx.example.com">
```

I tried to attached the image files(using the same name referenced in above html codes as attachment) but it will just be attachment and won't be shown in the text body as embed image. **Our mail serve doesn't support SMTP protocol, so I cannot use the smtplib** as that in [Sending Multipart html emails which contain embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920910/python-sending-multipart-html-emails-which-contain-embedded-images). Can somebody help me out? thanks in advance!

```
    attachment1 = "G:\\image001.png"
    Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
```

2013/8/8 Update, I got a C# version codes via http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c063b27-7e8a-4963-ad5f-ce7e5ffb2c64/how-to-embed-image-in-html-body-in-c-into-outlook-mail, could anybody show me Python counterpart codes for these:

```
   Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(
                      @"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg"
                      , OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
                      , null
                      , "Some image display name"
                     );

   string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";

   attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
                     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
                     , imageCid
                     );

    newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format(
                      "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
                     , imageCid
                     );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = o.CreateItem(0)

attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add("E:\Pictures\image001.jpg", win32com.client.constants.olEmbeddeditem, 0, "Some image display name")
imageCid = "image001.jpg@123"
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid)
newMail.HTMLBody = "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>".format(imageCid)

msg.Send()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In python you must define before the property PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W because it's not defined in pywin32 mapitags (win32com.mapi.mapitags)

```
from win32com.mapi.mapitags import PROP_TAG, PT_UNICODE 

# defines the property PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W  not defined  in    pywin32 mapitags.
# number of PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W Property is in MSDN Library
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765868.aspx
# all mapi tags are defined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815492%28v=office.15%29.aspx
mapitags.PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W = PROP_TAG(PT_UNICODE, 0x3712)

# now you can use the property PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W like Dmitry explained you.
```

Answer (score -2):

Take one HTML page, with your text content and CSS

Grab an image you want to send embedded in your email

Use a Base64 encoder to turn your binary photo into a huge text string
(like: http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64)

Replace your normal image source with that string

Save your file and send as normal

Comment: Thanks for your info, i tried but failed, it seems that outlook doesn't support Base64 encoded image well, whereas I save the email content as .html and open it in IE, the image displays very well...

Comment: Outlook uses Word to render inline images, and it does not support embedded images. You need to set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property on the attachment to match the cid attribute on the img tag. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968356/vml-base64-image/16968736#16968736

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, i could not access the msdn web metioned in the post you gave, but I guess from PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property, it should be the usage in C#, right? So do know a python version for it? Thanks