# Picture sent in body (not attached) by automated E-Mail

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

How can I send an image within an E-Mail, but not as an attachment?

The image will be combined with some generated number, that Access provides.

> Thank You for registration bla, bla, bla... Your generated number, that you need to sign is (for example) 123456789. Please sign it in bla, bla, bla...

I have code that sends E-Mail with generated number within. It is only text.

```vb
Private Sub D001_Click()

'Program za registrovanje novog zaposlenog
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Registrovani (Ime, Prezime, Korisnicko_ime, Lozinka, Adresa, Broj, Dodatak, Postanski_broj, Grad, Drzava, Telefon, Elektronska_adresa) VALUES('" & Me.IZ & "', '" & Me.PZ & "', '" & Me.KIZ & "', '" & Me.LZ & "', '" & Me.APZ & "', " & Me.BAPZ & ", '" & Me.DBAPZ & "', " & Me.PBZ & ", '" & Me.GZ & "', '" & Me.DZ & "', '" & Me.KTZ & "', '" & Me.EAZ & "')"

'Program za slanje automatske elektronske poste sa kodnim brojem
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Poštovani," & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "ovo je automatska poruka poslata od strane programa, na koju NE TREBA da odgovorite." & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "Poslata je u svrhu Vaše registracije, a u vezi provere Vašeg identiteta." & vbNewLine & _
    "Potrebno je da dobijeni kodni broj sa svim svojim karakterima ukucate nazad u bazu podataka, na definisano mesto." & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "Vaš kodni broj je:" & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    DLookup("ID", "Registrovani", "[Korisnicko_ime]='" & Me.KIZ.Value & "'") & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "U koliko niste u procesu registracije, neko pokušava Vašu elektronsku poštu da zloupotrebi!" & vbNewLine & _
    "Hitno preduzmite sve potrebne korake radi zaštite Vaših podataka!" & vbNewLine & _
    "U toj situaciji, sadržaj ovog elektronskog pisma možete ignorisati." & vbNewLine & _
    "" & vbNewLine & _
    "Hvala na razumevanju i pažnji."

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Me.EAZ.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Registracija"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add 'npr. ("C:\Users\10466237\Desktop\1111111111111111111111111111111111111.jpg")
        .Send 'ili mozes samo prikazati elektronsku poruku pomocu komande .Display ili oboje (poslati i prikazati)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Me.IZ = Null
    Me.PZ = Null
    Me.KIZ = Null
    Me.LZ = Null
    Me.APZ = Null
    Me.BAPZ = Null
    Me.DBAPZ = Null
    Me.PBZ = Null
    Me.GZ = Null
    Me.DZ = Null
    Me.KTZ = Null
    Me.EAZ = Null
    DoCmd.Close acForm, 1
    DoCmd.OpenForm (500)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you create the mail as text or HTML mail?

Comment: It's probably easiest to create the mails from a template instead of from scratch. Use `Set oItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(sPathToTemplate)` instead of `Set oItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)`. Then replace keyword(s) in the HTMLBody with your variables.

Comment: Try it step by step, this looks to be a nice example of what you are looking for... https://www.codevba.com/outlook/email-with-picture-in-body.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MathiasZ: that's an attachment, not an inline image.

Comment: Yes, that is old code with attachment.  I would like to improve it to have picture in body of E-Mail.  Community asked me to provide code and I did it.

Comment: fyi - Before you try the suggested duplicate remove `On Error Resume Next` so you can debug if necessary. In general remove `On Error Resume Next` from all code you find where it is followed by `With OutMail`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting plaintext `Body` property, use `HTMLBody` property instead.

Your <`img>` tag can either

1. embed the picture as base64 encoded string (`<img  src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRB.../>`') (older versions of Outlook won't display it)
2. Add the image as an attachment (`Attachments.Add`), set `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the attachment, and refer to that `cid` (`src=cid:xyz`) in the `img` tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968736/332059. This works in all email clients.

Answer (score 0):

The following code sets a plain text message body and attaches a file (image):

```
With OutMail
        .To = Me.EAZ.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Registracija"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add 'npr. ("C:\Users\10466237\Desktop\1111111111111111111111111111111111111.jpg")
        .Send 'ili mozes samo prikazati elektronsku poruku pomocu komande .Display ili oboje (poslati i prikazati)
    End With
```

If you want to get your attached image displayed in the message body you need:

1. Use the `HTMLBody` property instead of `Body`. That change will allow displaying rich UI including images and other text formatting.
2. In the message body string you need to add the `img` tag with your image in the following way:

```
.HTMLBody = "<html><body><img src=""cid:Image.jpg""height=520 width=750></body></html>"
```

where the `Image.jpg` is the name of the attached file.

Sometimes you need to set the content ID of your attached file explicitly so that you could use that value in the message body, for example:

```
attachment = attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "AttachmentId1")
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:AttachmentId1""></body></html>"
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the explanation and time. I have problem with line:
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "AttachmentId1")
Something is wrong with the part ".PropertyAccessor.", it is always red and reports an compile error: syntax error?!

Comment: The [Attachment.PropertyAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.propertyaccessor) is a valid property. Make sure that you added a reference to the Outlook object model in your project, i.e. use the early-binding.